# Powershell script to change operator email address notification

Tags: sql-server, powershell

This is the script I have been trying to get work:

```
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null

$server = "servername"

$srv = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $server

$op = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Operator") $srv.JobServer, "DBA Team"

$op.emailAddress = "johndoe@gmail.com" 
$op.alter
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please specify what your problem is, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

To change the email address for an existing operator use this.

```
$srv.JobServer.Operators.Item('DBA Team').EmailAddress = 'johndoe@gmail.com'
$srv.JobServer.Operators.Item('DBA Team').Alter()
```

Your code is almost what you would use to add a new operator.